# HTMl File Input with PhoneGap not working in IPhone

Tags: iphone, html, file-upload, cordova

I am developing an simple IPhone app which will let me select picture from my phone pictures and will upload it to the HTTP server. I know there is a FileUpload plugin for phonegap but how to let user select the picture from their? Is there any plugin for that or I would have to write myself?

The HTML Input type File control doesn't work and it's obvious why it won't work because it's designed for something else. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, `<input type="file" />` does not work in this way.

If you want to select an image from the device photos, you can use [PhoneGap's Camera API](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html) and specify a [sourceType option parameter](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions) allowing you to choose an image from the photo gallery / saved photo albums on the device.

I would recommend reading the entire page, especially the bottom "Quirks" section, as there are some differences across the various supported platforms.